# I cannot disable a (ghost) breakpoint

Tags: delphi, ide, breakpoints, delphi-xe

I have an IDE break point (delphi-xe) that keeps reappearing every time I compile and run the program.
How do I get rid of it. Where does Delphi keep the information about breakpoints?

Updates:
1. The break point is not listed in 'Breakpoints' panel.
2. I have disabled the breakpoint (it is not gray) using right click but the program still stops on that 
line.
3. I have deleted the line and the breakpoint moved above.

---

Update
It happens when you edit files outside the IDE. I do this a lot in BeyondCompare.

Comment: Is it really a Delphi breakpoint or an int 3; in some 3rd party code that might have left some debug code in place?

Comment: Hi Lars. It appears as a red dot on the right side of the editor. The PAS file in which it appears is mine (created by me).

Comment: Welcome to the world of ghost and mysteriously moving as well as disappearing and re-appearing breakpoints. I'd check if the unit has any conditional defines. It seems to mess with the editor's ability to keep track of breakpoints. At least, since D2009 I haven't been able to set breakpoints and edit a unit without something going awry. It seems worse when conditional defines are in the picture, but I have yet to track it down sufficiently to file a QC report.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two versions of that unit? Ie one which has the preakpoint and is actually used by the project and other which is open in the editor?

Comment: @Ain. The path shown in the top of the editor is the same. Let me know if there is some other test I can do to detect that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been a bug in Delphi since at least Delphi 7.

Workaround: Delete all breakpoints or disable breakpoint from breakpoint window.

Workaround 2: Delete .dsk files and .local files.

Comment: God! That old? I am happy that I never stepped into it (at least until now).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before and I found out that a file with the same filename was being referenced by the IDE that had break points. So do a search for your file and make sure that another file with the same name is not being referenced also.

Comment: The path shown in the top of the editor is the same (when I click the red dot to disable it and when the breakpoint reappears). Let me know if there is some other test I can do to detect that.

Comment: 1) do you have multiple projects in the project manager that have files with the same name? 2) there is a annoying bug in the IDE where it can reference the wrong file during debugging if you #1 3) search your project folder(s) and make sure you do not have any other files with the same name that the IDE maybe referencing during debugging. It was because of #1 that I had the issue.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR breakpoints are stored in the project's .dsk file. So deleting that file should solve the issue.
(I seem to remember that .dsk are in .ini Format so you might even be able to find out what causes the behaviour.)

Comment: Found the reference to my file 3 (three) times in the DSK file. Deleted the entire section 'breakpoints'. Now it works. I am happy that Embarcadero put accent on productivity by offering this nice IDE. Because I spent may minutes every time I ran the program clicking the F9 button to jump over that damn ghost breakpoint - so probably I spent many hours on nothing. Thanks a lot Dummzeuch. YOU increased my productivity! Accepted.

Comment: It is possible to do it inside the IDE too. :-) You need the breakpoint window though. (View ->Debug ->Breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread, but I found a workaround which might help and which is not directly  mentioned here.
If its a INT 3-Problem take a look at Embarcadero Quality Central Report #:  2030 (http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2030). This problem is still not solved in Rad studio XE !!

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 0):

Still hasn't been solved in Rad Studio 10.4 (using c++). I deleted the .dsk and .local files and it cleared the breakpoint.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22266669)